# Hacker replace .htaccess and index.php at public folder

Tags: php, laravel, security, server

i am using laravel 5.6 and having issue with someone keep replace .htaccess and index.php file at public folder

and sometimes he/she add some other php file or altering my index.blade.php files at resource/view folder

how to improve my security to prevent?

here is all my package that i am using for the project

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.1.3",
        "alexusmai/laravel-file-manager": "^2.5",
        "artesaos/seotools": "^0.12.1",
        "awobaz/compoships": "^2.1",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "0.8.*",
        "cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable": "^4.5.2",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~4.0",
        "intervention/image": "^2.4",
        "jenssegers/date": "^3.4",
        "laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
        "laravel/passport": "^5.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "lcobucci/jwt": "3.3.1",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
        "predis/predis": "^1.1",
        "pusher/pusher-php-server": "^4.1",
        "spatie/laravel-activitylog": "^2.5",
        "spatie/laravel-analytics": "^3.6",
        "spatie/laravel-cors": "^1.0",
        "spatie/laravel-medialibrary": "^7.0.0",
        "spatie/laravel-permission": "^2.9",
        "tymon/jwt-auth": "^1.0.0",
        "venturecraft/revisionable": "^1.28",
        "watson/rememberable": "^3.2",
        "yadahan/laravel-authentication-log": "^1.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "~1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "~1.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~7.0",
        "symfony/thanks": "^1.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "files": [
            "app/cdn.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "kylekatarnls/update-helper": true,
            "symfony/thanks": true
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Comment: First you need to find out how they are getting in. Start by changing all your passwords for FTP,SSH,Hosting package, etc etc etc. Make sure you use STRONG password and not something simple that can be guessed or brute forced easily

Comment: And start looking for backdoor php files.

Comment: Laravel 5.6 have Security Fixes Until February 7th, 2019

- upgrade your laravel and vendor.
- change your passwords

Comment: okay, already change FTP, SSH, hosting, panel, all that have password and also removing ssh key etc hopefully it will fixed it...

so upgrading laravel is being planned but i confuse which version should i go that don't have many breaking changes?

Comment: well you should really upgrade to laravel 9 as the rest no longer have security patches (8 will only until Jan) https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/releases#support-policy